# Serializing rows of key/value pairs into a JSON object

Tags: json, data-structures, facebook-opengraph

I need help transforming this table of data:

```
[
    {property:"key", content:"1"},
    {property:"key", content:"2"},
    {property:"key2", content:"3"},
    {property:"key2:subkey", content:"4"},
    {property:"key2:someother:key", content:"5"},
    {property:"foo", content:"6"},
    {property:"foo", content:"7"},
    {property:"foo:bar", content:"8"}
]
```

into a JSON object with the following structure:

```
{
  key: ["1", "2"],
  key2: {
    '': "3"
    subkey: "4"
    someother: {
      key: "5"
    }
  },
  foo: [
    "6",
    {
      '': "7"
      bar: "8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the rules. Note: all rules apply to any level in the JSON object (json.levelOne, json.level.two, json.level.three.even, etc)

1. For each `row.property` like `"a:b:c"` should translate into `json.a.b.c = row.content`.
2. When `row.property = "x"` and `json.x !== undefined` then `json.x = [json.x, row.content]`
3. Whenever `json.x === "string"` and `row.property = "x:y"` then `json.x = {'': json.x, y: row.content}`
4. Whenever `Array.isArray(json.x) && json.x[json.x.length-1] === "string"` and `row.property = "x:y"` then `json.x[json.x.length-1] = {'': json.x[json.x.length-1], y: row.content}`

Hopefully that gives you some idea as to the criteria of what I need to do to translate the data into this JSON object format.

## Why?

I'm trying to take Open Graph meta data and serialize it into a JSON object. I feel like the format above would best reflect the Open Graph meta data structure. I need help writing this algorithm though. This is for an open source Node.js project that I'm working on.

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

## edit

So there are some issue left to the parser. Arrays occur at leaf nodes in some cases.

Here is the project on GitHub: https://github.com/samholmes/node-open-graph Feel free to fork it, build a better parse, and send me a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated per our discussion on IRC

```
var data = [
    {property:"key", content:"1"},
    {property:"key", content:"2"},
    {property:"key2", content:"3"},
    {property:"key2:subkey", content:"4"},
    {property:"key2:someother:key", content:"5"},
    {property:"foo", content:"6"},
    {property:"foo", content:"7"},
    {property:"foo:bar", content:"8"},
    {property:"foo:baz", content:"9"}
];

var transformed = {};

data.forEach(function (item) {
    var key, tmp,
        ptr = transformed,
        keys = item.property.split(':');

    // we want to leave one key to assign to so we always use references
    // as long as there's one key left, we're dealing with a sub-node and not a value

    while (keys.length > 1) {
        key = keys.shift();

        if (Array.isArray(ptr[key])) {
            // the last index of ptr[key] should become
            // the object we are examining.
            tmp = ptr[key].length-1;
            ptr = ptr[key];
            key = tmp;
        }

        if (typeof ptr[key] === 'string') {
            // if it's a string, convert it
            ptr[key] = { '': ptr[key] };
        } else if (ptr[key] === undefined) {
            // create a new key
            ptr[key] = {};
        }

        // move our pointer to the next subnode
        ptr = ptr[key];
    }

    // deal with the last key
    key = keys.shift();

    if (ptr[key] === undefined) {
        ptr[key] = item.content;
    } else if (Array.isArray(ptr[key])) {
        ptr[key].push(item.content);
    } else {
        ptr[key] = [ ptr[key], item.content ];
    }
});
console.log(transformed);
```

Outputs:

```
{
    key: ['1', '2'],
    key2: {
        '': '3',
        subkey: '4',
        someother: {
            key: '5'
        }
    },
    foo: ['6', {
        '': '7',
        bar: '8'
        baz: '9'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this on freenode.net #node.js. Here are some modifications I made to this code that makes it just right: http://jsfiddle.net/3MVAd/2/ I'm wondering if I could clean up what I did a bit more.

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much! :D I'll give you credit in the github project for sure.